# how do i show the amount of time elapsed from a certain date in html?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I make a "live" time counter in html? For example, I show the number of months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds that have passed since 1/1/2001 and I want to see it ticking upwards. How would I do that? I don't know JS lol, but I do remember once making the same thing but it displayed the time until a certain date using just one HTML file. I don't recall how I did it though.

Answer (score 2):

### You can use the below package

> [javascript-time-ago](https://github.com/catamphetamine/javascript-time-ago)

```
// Load locale-specific relative date/time formatting rules.
import en from 'javascript-time-ago/locale/en'
 
// Add locale-specific relative date/time formatting rules.
TimeAgo.addLocale(en)
 
// Create relative date/time formatter.
const timeAgo = new TimeAgo('en-US')
 
timeAgo.format(new Date())
// "just now"
 
timeAgo.format(Date.now() - 60 * 1000)
// "a minute ago"
 
timeAgo.format(Date.now() - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
// "2 hours ago"
 
timeAgo.format(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
// "a day ago"
```

Comment: use the above logic in a js file and take the reference of the HTML element in which you want to render it and keep it updating

Answer (score 1):

If you want one, go to this [site](https://www.tickcounter.com/countup). You can make a custom one with them. If you want to write one from scratch, go to their GitHub page and tune it to your liking.

Comment: that one wants me to pay or show a link. what's their github?

Comment: @dairy My bad, they have no GitHub. I saw a "clone" button and assumed. You may be able to save their page locally and stitch the files together to work.